# Variação percentual anual no R com dplyr

Tags: r

Estava querendo utilizar o pacote `dplyr` para calcular a variação anual do `IFGF` entre um ano e outro e de 2006 a 2016.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão? Fiz algumas tentativas frustradas como:

```
graca_evolucao_ifgf%>%

select(Ano, IFGF) %>%

group_by(Ano) %>%

mutate(Variacao = (IFGF/lag(IFGF))-1*100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa fazer `group_by` neste caso:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ano = 2001:2010, indice = runif(10))

df %>% 
  mutate(variacao = (indice/lag(indice, 1, order_by = ano) - 1)*100)
#>     ano    indice  variacao
#> 1  2001 0.4541271        NA
#> 2  2002 0.9796882 115.72997
#> 3  2003 0.6316009 -35.53042
#> 4  2004 0.7608055  20.45669
#> 5  2005 0.6707154 -11.84141
#> 6  2006 0.5535272 -17.47212
#> 7  2007 0.4728882 -14.56821
#> 8  2008 0.1902217 -59.77449
#> 9  2009 0.3954753 107.90230
#> 10 2010 0.8191409 107.12822
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Daniel Falbel, graças à sua resposta consegui realizar o que eu desejava. Obrigado!